# Calculate Sum, Average and 90% in DB/2

Tags: sql, db2

If I have the following table called `stats`:

```
type    duration
------  ---------
get     10
get     15
get     20
put     12
put     14
put     16
```

I know I can get the `sum()` and `average()` with a query like:

```
select
    type, 
    sum(duration) as "total duration",
    avg(duration) as "average duration"
from
    stats
group by
    type
```

And I can also get the 90% `avg()` and `max()` duration using window function features:

```
select
    type,
    avg("dur") as "average duration of the fastest 90%",
    max("dur") as "max duration of the fastest 90%"
from
(
    select
        type,
        duration as "dur",
        row_number() over (partition by type order by duration asc) as "seqnum"
        count(*) over (partition by type) as "totnum"
    from
        stats
)
where
    "seqnum" <= (.9 * "totnum")
group by
    type
```

But I'm struggling to understand how I can merge the two together so that I can have one query that returns: `type`, `total duration`, `average duration`, `average duration of the fastest 90%`, `max duration of the fastest 90%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select type,
       sum(duration) as "total duration",
       avg(duration) as "average duration",
       avg(case when "seqnum" <= (0.9 * "totnum") then "dur" end) as "average duration of the fastest 90%",
       max(case when "seqnum" <= (0.9 * "totnum") then "dur" end) as "max duration of the fastest 90%"
from (select type, duration as "dur",
             row_number() over (partition by type order by duration asc) as "seqnum",
             count(*) over (partition by type) as "totnum"
      from stats
     ) s
group by type;
```

Comment: so the `case when "seqnum" < (0.9 * "totnum") then "dur" end` means, "if it meets the criteria then use it in the aggregation function else don't use it?"

Comment: @MattFelzani . . . Basically.  What it actually means is evaluate the expression; the `else` clause is `NULL`.  Most aggregation functions ignore `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
select distinct
    type,
    avg("dur") over(partition by type) as "average duration of the fastest 90%",
    max("dur") over(partition by type) as "max duration of the fastest 90%",
    "total duration",
    "average duration"
from
(
    select
        type,
        duration as "dur",
        row_number() over (partition by type order by duration asc) as "seqnum",
        count(*) over (partition by type) as "totnum",
        sum(duration) over(partition by type) as "total duration",
        avg(duration) over(partition by type) as "average duration"
    from
        stats
) x
where 
    "seqnum" <= (.9 * "totnum")
```

Comment: but won't that give me the four stats for just the 90%? i want the total and average for 100%, then the other two for just the 90%?

Comment: it will give you the total and average for 100%,because sum(duration) over(partition by type) and avg(duration) over(partition by type) would be the same for all rows of a given type in the inner query. you can run the inner query and check.

Comment: ah, i just saw that part. that's cool. basically *all* of the rows carry those two 100% fields with them.

i'll give that a try and award the coveted check box once i prove it out.

thank you!